# What Color Are Black Holes Really? (Yes, a serious question)

Tags: visible-light, black-holes

So I got into a mini-debate in science class today because I proposed that [black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) aren't really black, they only look black because light can't reflect off them. But if you were to take the material that makes up that black hole and decrease it's density so that gravity isn't so strong that light can't reflect, then what color will this new object be? Think of it like this: if you put a red apple in a room that is completely pitch black, the apple will appear black but it's actually red (we just can't observe this because there's no light).

Comment: If you decreased the gravity to the point light can reflect, it would cease to be a black hole

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The material part of a black hole is (classically) compressed into a zero volume area, and almost all of the information of the matter that eventually became the black hole was dissipated away, so the original notion of your question is unanswerable.

There IS another sense in which we can think of your question, though.  Black holes are known to shine light through a process known as Hawking radiation, which has a blackbody spectrum.  To first approximation, stars are known to also have a blackbody spectrum.

The key point there is that the blackbody spectrum's color is determined by the temperature of the distribution.  In the case of stars, this means that the hotter the star, the bluer the color of the star.  For black holes, the more massive the star, the redder the blackbody distribution.  For black holes that have masses anywhere near that of the sun, the "color" of the star will be very, very far into the radio edge of the light spectrum, and therefore, the black hole will not be visible to the naked eye.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes much more sense now.

Comment: At some point during their life they will heat up enough to become visible, though. If we believe http://xaonon.dyndns.org/hawking/, then a 5800K black hole has a radius of $3.141749\times 10^{-8}m$ (i.e. the size of a small virus), a mass of $2.115868\times 10^{19} kg$ (the mass of a large mountain and a luminosity of $7.959627\times 10^{-7} W$ (barely enough to be visible with the naked eye from a few meters, I think).  One couldn't get close enough to see it with bare eyes, though, the gravity would be a killer at that distance. I might be wrong about that bit.

Comment: @CuriousOne: yes, I'm talking about stellar mass black holes at a time within the natural lifetime of the sun from now.  At arbitrarily late times, the black hole mass goes to zero, so the temperature will eventually diverge.  But that's not really relevant to the question, at least as I see it.

Comment: If someone is asking for the color of a black hole, the actual answer can only be "When?", since it changes. There is no valid physical reason to apply an anthropomorphic time scale. We are not the ones setting the pace in this universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne We are doing all of the observing, though, and talking about anything that requires a timescale larger than 13.6 billion years is kind of silly and close to being outside the realm of science.

Comment: Also, any realistic model of decay has the rate of decay accelerating as the mass decreases, and asymptoting as $M\rightarrow 0$, so most black holes will generically spend the vast, vast majority of their lives with Hawking radiation peaked very far in the radio

Comment: We aren't doing "all of the observing", either. Nature can observe herself just fine (that's what she invented QFT for). Time to let go of the anthropocentric thinking. Seriously. We are merely a fluke of nature bound to an extremely small phase space volume and she can do without us just fine. Our role is not to enlarge ourselves into something we are not (and will never be), it's to understand nature's dynamics on all scales. Not sure why you think that "time" is somehow a linear coordinate axis phenomenon. That's only the human short term approximation. Logarithms are fine for nature.

Comment: @CuriousOne we can't.  We can't understand anything on a scale larger than the age of the universe, because there are no observations to make, and science doesn't work without observations.  It's epistemologically impossible.

Comment: But it's not as arrogant as to say that everything stops once I am gone. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: not my statement.  My statement is that our knowledge ends.

Comment: The third law of thermodynamics doesn't end once you close your eyes for the last time.

Comment: @CuriousOne: no, but I don't know anything about the hawking radiation profile of small-mass black holes, and neither do you.  For all we know, there's some sort of ground state in the completed quantum theory.  And I think you mean the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I am actually with you there. I am not sure the universe will ever get that old, however, as far as black holes are concerned, I am kind of confident that we are pretty close to the facts there. Black holes are the most boring objects in the universe and they are as close to the fine print of thermodynamics as a physical system can possibly come.  I did mean the third law: nothing can have a temperature of 0K. One doesn't have to get fancy with math to apply that to black holes. If we acknowledge that they are also close to equilibrium and shapeless, then they have to be black bodies.

Comment: But a zero degree black hole is either extremal or has infinite mass, so I don't see how it applies to this problem.